# Fragments and Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

When trying to run our app, we consistently have errors with conflicting fragments not letting us run the activity. Here's a [screencast](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-DqDtvWwiKteThDNWoyRzVzMlU/view) of the problem I am facing

As you can see, the app itself contains a multitude of problems, but my primary focus is getting the clicker to respond on the click. Here is the class page for the clicker activity:

```
package com.example.android.Chapsnat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;




public class ContactsFragment extends AppCompatActivity {



Button btnClick;
Button btnReset;

TextView txtCount;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_contacts);



    btnClick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
    btnReset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonReset);
    txtCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewCount);


    btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String countValue = txtCount.getText().toString();
            int intCountValue = Integer.parseInt(countValue);
            intCountValue++;

            txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(intCountValue));

        } });

    btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(0));
        }
    });


}


}
```

And this is the xml page it is being built in, which is also a fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_contacts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.Chapsnat.ContactsFragment">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_purple"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<Button
    android:text="Click"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewCount"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="79dp" />

<Button
    android:text="Reset"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="171dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonReset"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewCount"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonClick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there any way you can help? If so please let me know.

Comment: Your ContactsFragment isn't a Fragment, it's an Activity. You need to put all of the onClickListener logic in to the appropriate Fragment....show all of your code.

Comment: Where is this variable "intCountValue" defined ??

Comment: What is the name of your xml file?  I assume it is "fragment_contacts.xml" but it's better if you're specific about this.

Comment: Sorry for the not responding sooner, but yes Garry99 the xml file is "fragment_contacts.xml". As for Mark F that is all the code we have, and thanks for your feed back.